# How to load splash screen from image file

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen

I use an image as the splash screen by adding the following line:

`SplashScreen-Image: com/package1/splashimage.png`

to the `manifest.mf` file, which requires my `splashimage.png` to be included in the jar file. What I want to do now is to put that image file outside the jar file (i.e. as a separate file). How do I do that? Thank you.

Comment: *"What I want to do now is to put that image file outside the jar file"*  Why?  If the program is not 'only for you' then it would be better to do it always as a Jar containing the resources.  Use a build tool/IDE to collect the classes and other resources, and write the Manifest to the Jar at the touch of a key combo.

Answer (score 2):

`SplashScreen-Image` requires a path. For further details read - [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)

```
SplashScreen-Image: com/package1/splashimage.png
```